# What will I get from the KieBuilder.getResults().getMessages() function if the KieBuilder.buildAll() is success?

Tags: java, drools

I have a KieFileSystem(kFile) from which the KieBuilder(kbuilder) is built.

```
kbuilder = kService.newKieBuilder(kFile).buildAll();
                System.out.println("Messages in KBuilder after BuildAll : "+kbuilder.getResults().getMessages().toString());
```

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: I am getting an empty Array.. My KieBase does not contain any KiePackage. So I doubt whether something should be there if Build of KieBuilder is success..

Comment: There's your answer then ;)

Comment: If you want to see error messages if any during build then you can use below approach: if (Kiebuilder.getResults().hasMessages(org.kie.api.builder.Message.Level.ERROR)) {
     throw new RuntimeException("Build Errors:\n"
      + Kiebuilder.getResults().toString());
 }